# select if word beginning with but not exist in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get from `phrase_table` all rows where `phrase` column contains words beginning with `be` (in this example) but exclude if the entire word exist in `stop_words_table` and NOT EXCLUDE if one word exist in `stop_words_table` but another not exist (see id=4 `be` and `because`)

```
phrase_table
id  phrase
1     would be fine
2     nothing to do
3     belgium is beautiful
4     this also must be included because I need
```

.

```
stopwords_table
id    word
1       be
```

.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT id FROM phrase_table
WHERE phrase REGEXP '[[:<:]]be' = 1
-- That return id 1,3,4

SELECT id FROM phrase_table
WHERE phrase REGEXP '[[:<:]]be' = 1
AND phrase NOT IN(
    SELECT * FROM stopwords_table WHERE word = 'be'
)
-- That return nothing because 'be' exists in stopwords_table
```

**ESPECTED RESULT**:

`id 3 and 4 from phrase_table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  If spaces are the separators between words, then I'm thinking:

```
select *
from phrase_table pt
where concat(' ', pt.phrase, ' ') regexp '[^ ]be|be[^ ]';
```

You can expand this into a `join` with something like:

```
select sw.word, pt.*
from phrase_table pt join
     stopwords_table sw
     on concat(' ', pt.phrase, ' ') regexp replace('[^ ]@sw|@sw[^ ]', '@sw', sw.word);
```

Comment: Yes separators is the space ... I will be try your solution

Comment: I have added `AND sw.word = @sw` to `ON` because get duplicate results and work. Thank's @Gordon Linoff